# How to select dropdown value in selenium webdriver using Testng?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can we select the dropdown value in selenium webdriver using Testng?

Comment: There aren't enough details in your post for us to help you.  Please add HTML for the dropdown, or a link to the website with the dropdown.  Also include what you have tried so far.

Comment: refer this : http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2013/04/Select.html

Answer (score 0):

Selecting dropdown values in selenium webdriver is not a part of TestNG, it's part of selenium+java code.

Use below code for reference ::

```
public class temp {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.shoppersstop.com/shoes/kids-shoes/all/brand/kittens.html");

    WebElement selectElement = driver.findElement(By
            .xpath("//select[@class='subCatThree' and @name='category']"));
    Select select = new Select(selectElement);
    List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();

    for (WebElement option : options) {
        System.out.println(option.getText());
        if (option.getText().equals("Girls ( 3 Years & Above)")) {
            option.click();
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select by value

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findelement(By.xpath("write the xpath of dropdown")));
    select.selectByValue("write value here");
```

If you want to select by Text

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findelement(By.xpath("write the xpath of dropdown")));
    select.selectByVisibleText("write text here");
```

Comment: Please add `selectByIndex` as well to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

How do we convert this code to use Selenium WebDriver

```
If Browser("UOB").Page("pgeSetCustomLimits").Exist(intSyncTime*1) Then
    Set oDesc=Description.Create        
    oDesc("micclass").Value = "WebElement"
    oDesc("html id").Value = "limitsInput_CI_form_label_div"
    Set ObjEle =
         Browser("UOB").Page("pgeSetCustomLimits").ChildObjects(oDesc)
    For i=0 to ObjEle.count-1
        strWebEleText = ObjEle(i).getRoProperty("innertext")
        'print strWebEleText
        If Instr(strWebEleText,strPaymentType) Then
            intRow = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End If
```