# How to select a dropdown value in Selenium WebDriver Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

Before posting, I researched across stackoverflow to solve this issue but could not find solution as most of them provide solution related to Select class. Some of the links that I did come across and did not solve my issue are below,

1. [How to select a dropdown value in Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138761/how-to-select-a-dropdown-value-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)
2. [How to select dropdown value in selenium webdriver using Testng?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114395/how-to-select-dropdown-value-in-selenium-webdriver-using-testng)
3. [How to select dropdown option from span in selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55586742/how-to-select-dropdown-option-from-span-in-selenium-webdriver)
4. [Selenium WebDriver: Handling DropDowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130974/selenium-webdriver-handling-dropdowns)
5. [Select dropdown in selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28935813/select-dropdown-in-selenium-webdriver)

I have 6 dropdown menus which has same dropdown list and same HTML tags.I am unable to select value from each dropdown menu. One of the dropdown menu looks like below,

[image: 1 of 6 dropdown menu]

I have HTML with dynamic div ids,

[image: HTML]

My xpath to select one of the options is as ->  //li[text()='No Problems']. Below method does click on Dropdown menu but fails to click on No Problems. I could not use Select class as DOM does not have select tag.

Below are the 2 different methods that I tried to select dropdown option,

[image: Method to Click on dropdown and select No Problems]

[image: Method 2 to select option from dropdown]

Please help how to overcome this scenario and select dropdown list option.

Answer (score 2):

```
// click on that place holder

     driver.findElement(By.xpath("....')).click();

// then store all results which are inside box by list classes in selenium 

        List <WebElement> lists=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@role='list box']//li"));
        System.out.println(lists.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
            //System.out.println(LIST.get(i).getText());
// checking that text by for loop and pick 
            if (lists.get(i).getText().contains("No Problems")) {
                lists.get(i).click();
                break;
            }
```

Comment: Welcome if my answer is satisfy to you please accept my answer so that others can get idea

Answer (score 0):

You can make select operations in selenium like that:

```
//1) 
Select objSelect =new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("search-box")));
objSelect.selectByVisibleText("Automation");

//2) 
Select objSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("Seacrch-box")));
Select.selectByIndex(4);

//3) 
Select objSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("Search-box")));
objSelect.selectByValue("Automation Testing");
```